# Issue with a manually instantiated SessionState provider

Tags: c#, mysql, session-state

I'm working on a prototype program, which should test different (SessionState, Profile, etc) providers for ASP.NET, i.e. MySQL, Oracle, etc. At the moment I'm using the MySQL provider. I've just managed to instantiate the provider, a SessionStateContainer and the SessionState itself.

```cs
Type mySqlType = Type.GetType("MySql.Web.SessionState.MySqlSessionStateStore, MySql.Web, Version=6.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d", true, true);

SessionStateStoreProviderBase provider = (SessionStateStoreProviderBase)Activator.CreateInstance(mySqlType);
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection providerConfig = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
providerConfig.Add("connectionStringName", "LocalMySqlServer");
providerConfig.Add("applicationName", "/");
providerConfig.Add("autogenerateschema", "True");
providerConfig.Add("enableExpireCallback", "False");

provider.Initialize("MySqlSessionStateProvider", providerConfig);

HttpContext context = new HttpContext(
                          new HttpRequest("fake", "http://localhost:14359", ""),
                          new HttpResponse(new StringWriter()));

SessionStateStoreData storeData = provider.CreateNewStoreData(context, 100);
System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionStateContainer sessionStateContainer =
    new System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionStateContainer(
            "mySession",
            storeData.Items,
            storeData.StaticObjects,
            100,
            true,
            System.Web.HttpCookieMode.UseDeviceProfile,
            SessionStateMode.Custom,
            false
    );

Type sessionStateType = Type.GetType("System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a");
HttpSessionState sessionState =
    (HttpSessionState)sessionStateType
        .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { typeof(IHttpSessionState) }, null)
        .Invoke(new object[] { ssessionStateContainer });

provider.InitializeRequest(context);
```

Everything seems to be working fine, as I'm able to write some values, in the session I created, and I'm able to read them from there:

```cs
sessionStateContainer.Add("SomeKey", "SomeValue");
var test = sessionStateContainer["SomeKey"];
Console.WriteLine("var test: " + test.ToString()); // outputs "var test: SomeValue"

sessionState.Add("AnotherKey", "SomeOtherValue");
var test2 = sessionState["AnotherKey"];
Console.WriteLine("var test2: " + test2.ToString()); // outputs "var test2: SomeOtherValue"

// End the request
provider.EndRequest(context);
```

Here comes the interesting part - when I inspect the `my_aspnet_sessions` table in the DB, there is nothing in there.

So I'm wondering where has the data been written or am I doing something wrong?

**Update:**
Even though this issue is no longer a blocker, I'm still curious to know and if anyone is up for giving it a try, here's the `connectionString` I've used:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <remove name="LocalMySqlServer" />
  <add name="LocalMySqlServer" connectionString="server=localhost;database=session_test;User Id=user;password=pass" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

You'd also need the [MySQL Connector NET](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

Comment: could you be clearing the data in this line by creating new `.Invoke(new object[] { ssessionStateContainer });` what happens when you step thru the code do you see any data at all..?

Comment: The two snippets are in the same order in my code. The writing of the data results after the instantiating of `sessionState`, so I don't see how it could be cleared? When stepping through the code I can see the keys `SomeKey` and `AnotherKey` in the corresponding properties, but more than that - not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see no data in the database because the [SessionStateModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.aspx) waits for the request end to invoke the command [SetAndReleaseItemExclusive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatestoreproviderbase.setandreleaseitemexclusive.aspx). The data are kept in memory until such command has been called. Indeed the documentation states:

> The SessionStateModule object calls the SetAndReleaseItemExclusive method at the end of a request, during the ReleaseRequestState event, to insert current session-item information into the data store or update existing session-item information in the data store with current values, to update the expiration time on the item, and to release the lock on the data. Only session data for the current application that matches the supplied session id and lockId values is updated. For more information about locking, see "Locking Session Store Data" in the SessionStateStoreProviderBase class overview.

To dive further into details, you can take a look at the [relevant files from the mono codebase](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.SessionState_2.0).

Given this, to see your session data in the database you should execute something like:

```cs
object storeLockId = new object();
sessionStateContainer.Add("SomeKey", "SomeValue");
var test = sessionStateContainer["SomeKey"];
Console.WriteLine("var test: " + test.ToString());

sessionState.Add("AnotherKey", "SomeOtherValue");
var test2 = sessionState["AnotherKey"];
Console.WriteLine("var test2: " + test2.ToString()); 

// End the request
provider.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive (context, sessionStateContainer.SessionID, 
                                     storeData, storeLockId, true);
provider.EndRequest(context);
```

Comment: I do have a call of the provider's `EndRequest()` method. Just updated the code snippet in my question.

Comment: @Havelock as you can see [here](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.SessionState_2.0/SessionSQLServerHandler.cs#l529) the stateprovider's EndRequest is often empty. The **SessionStateModule** calls **SetAndReleaseItemExclusive** in the **[OnRequestEnd](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.SessionState_2.0/SessionStateModule.cs#L325) handler** (via [OnReleaseRequestState](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.SessionState_2.0/SessionStateModule.cs#L278)).

Comment: Note that obviously the MS.NET implementation can be different, but the Mono's behaviour is conformant to the documentation (to minimize porting issues).

Comment: the downvote wasn't from me, but I'll gladly upvote it, as it seems to me, to be in the right direction. Unfortunately I don't have a lot of time atm, to fiddle with the code.

Comment: Added a code sample (note the lock object that was missing in your code). After the call at SetAndReleaseItemExclusive you should find the session items in the database.

Comment: That was it, `SetAndReleaseItemExclusive` did the job. Thanks a lot for the enlightment :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config, you need to set the mode="custom"

```
 <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="YourProvider">
```

Otherwise, session data will be stored in memory regardless of the provider.

Comment: The `Custom` mode is specified when instantiating the `HttpSessionStateContainer sessionStateContainer` (see the code above). Inspecting the fields when debugging showed that the mode is indeed `Custom`, so that's not the problem.

Comment: @Havelock - try turning on mysql logging.  See if there is anything being sent to mysql at all.  Maybe it's being sent to the DB, but not committed.

Comment: Good idea, but it didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Are any queries being sent to the DB?

Comment: Yes, but nothing related to the session data. The closest one relating was `SELECT ENGINE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='my_aspnet_sessions'`

Comment: That's good, it means your talking to the database successfully.  I looked at the code and INSERT's are sent on SetAndReleaseItemExclusive and CreateUninitializedItem, but you're only calling CreateNewStoreData.  I think that's where your issue lies.

Comment: For reference - https://gist.github.com/mrichman/405022#file-mysqlsessionstatestore-cs-L80